# Mail form php not working (blank screen)

Tags: php

I have some problems with sending an form to mail. I dont see why the screen becomes blank of going to the handler. I al so want to send and mail to the sender that the mail is recieved. (a lot off dutch in the strings, this will i edit later if you just make it english of not understanding dutch, thanks for helping).
This code is in my html index.php:

```
<form action="assets/inc/handlerofferte.php" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="naam" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Naam">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-mail">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <select class="form-control" name="onderwerp"  placeholder="Voor">
                                  <option value="" disabled selected>Betreft (selecteer)</option>
                                  <option value="plaatsing">Plaatsing</option>
                                  <option value="herstelling">Herstelling</option>
                                  <option value="renovatie">Renovatie</option>
                                  <option value="andere">Andere</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" name="meters" placeholder="Geschat aantal meters">
                                  <br>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="beschrijving" placeholder="Beschrijving"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">AANVRAGEN</button>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           </form>
```

My php handler is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "info@webtex.be "; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
    $subject = "Aanvraag offerte";
    $subject2 = "Bedankt voor uw aanvraag";
    $message = $naam . " voor:" . $onderwerp . " Extra informatie" . "\n\n" . $_POST['bericht'];
    $message2 = "Bedankt uw offerte aanvraag " . $naam . "\n\n" . $_POST['bericht'];

    $headers = "Van:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "Van:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $naam . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` will never fire up; name your submit button. "Blank screen" => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I tried to change this: <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">AANVRAGEN</button>

Comment: Now i get this: Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in D:\appdata\IIS\vhosts\webtex.be\demis.webtex.be\assets\inc\handlerofferte.php on line 14
Mail Sent. Thank you maiky, we will contact you shortly.

Comment: the problem here is that `Van:` probably means "From" in your language. PHP's `mail()` syntax http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php is not language dependant on other languages but "English". So change all your `Van:` to `From:`

Comment: Hi yes, thanks: but i tried this already:  $headers = "Form:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: `$headers = "Form:` typo, `$headers = "From:`

Comment: Hi thanks friend! It worked :)

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers*